# APNs notification

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

How many notification I can send from my iOS server to my iPhone app using APNs? e.g if I send 5 different APNs notification messages to my iPhone app, which was powered off at the time I sent those notifications, will it get all those 5 notifications when it come back to live

Comment: yes, when the app will back all the notification will be delivered.

Comment: It depends if you switched off your device and then how long it is switched off , there is no 100% surity you will get all push notification.

Comment: but I saw somewhere that, "when there is no network connectivity on a device the APNs stores only one notification per app. If a second notification to the same app arrives, then the first notification is replaced by the second"

Comment: yeah it will store all the notifications. Just make sure to add higher TTL in your push service. To make sure notification stays in APN queue for few days. Default is 28 days.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Apple documentation :

Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it when the device becomes available again. This component stores only the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes the previous request to be discarded. If a device remains offline for a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded.

To allow the coalescing of similar notifications, you can include a collapse identifier within a notification request. Normally, when a device is online, each notification request that you send to APNs results in a notification delivered to the device. However, when the apns-collapse-id key is present in your HTTP/2 request header, APNs coalesces requests whose value for that key is the same. For example, a news service that sends the same headline twice could use the same collapse identifier value for both requests. APNs would then coalesce the two requests into a single notification for delivery to the device. For details on the apns-collapse-id keyed.